# Task that executes a specific task in all included builds

Tags: gradle

I have a root project that includes quite a number of other projects via `includeBuild` in `settings.gradle`. All the subprojects have a task named `publishToMavenLocal`.

How can I define a task `publishToMavenLocal` in the root project that calls each `publishToMavenLocal` of each subproject without the need to manually define `dependsOn` for every subproject specifically?

Answer (score 1):

This use-case is actually covered in the [documentation on composite builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html#included_build_task_dependencies). The following code adapts the example from the documentation to your use-case:

```
task publishToMavenLocal {
    dependsOn gradle.includedBuilds*.task(':publishToMavenLocal')
}
```